# Using @lang directive als default value of @yield directive in Blade/Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, internationalization, laravel-blade

Regarding the Laravel documentation, the `@yield` directive in a blade template can have a default value as second argument. Since I'm developing a multi language site, how is it possible to use the `@lang` directive as default value?

I've already tried:

```
@yield('title', @lang('title'))
@yield('title', lang('title'))
```

neither of them is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Lang::get()` or `trans()` to get the localized version of your string:

```
@yield('title', trans('title'))
```

Comment: Or even `trans('title')` for a shorter and cleaner syntax